# GPS activation on Android

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver

In my application, How can I detect when GPS is turn on by other application installed on device?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check what app is able to get a location data by reading apps permissions with PackageManager class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Answer (score 0):

steps -

1. Create services running in backgroud
2. You require following permission in Manifest file too -

   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
3. write code

   final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService    (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

   if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) )
   Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is disable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    else
     Toast.makeText(context, "GPS is Enable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
4. Or simply you can check

   LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
   boolean statusOfGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
5. run your services continuous to monitor connection